# Multiple Joins + Lots of Data Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a massive join at work and have very limited resources in terms of being able to add indexes and such as well as what I can do in the query itself due to the environment (i.e. I can only select data, no variables or table creations allowed).  I have read somewhere that a subquery will automatically index the result, is this true?  Also for my major join tables (3) each has ~140K rows.  I have to join 2 extra tables to ensure filtering is correct.  I have the query listed below which I currently have criteria on the JOIN clause.  Another question is if I move my criteria to a where clause either in or out of the subquery will it benefit?

```
  SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT          NULL AS A1, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.TECHID, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.RONUMBER, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.CUSTOMERNUMBER, 
                        DFS_CUSTOMER.BNAME, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.UNITNUMBER, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.MILEAGE, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.OPENEDDATE, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.CLOSEDDATE, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.STATUS, 
                        DFS_ROHEADER.PONUMBER, 
                        DFS_TECH.REGION, 
                        DFS_TECH.RSM, 
                        DFS_ROPART.PARTID, 
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DFS_RODETAIL.STORY) AS STORY 
        FROM   DFS_ROHEADER 
               LEFT JOIN DFS_CUSTOMER 
                      ON DFS_ROHEADER.CUSTOMERNUMBER = DFS_CUSTOMER.CUST_NO 
               LEFT JOIN DFS_TECH 
                      ON DFS_ROHEADER.TECHID = DFS_TECH.TECHID 
               INNER JOIN DFS_RODETAIL 
                       ON DFS_ROHEADER.RONUMBER = DFS_RODETAIL.RONUMBER 
               INNER JOIN DFS_ROPART 
                       ON DFS_RODETAIL.RONUMBER = DFS_ROPART.RONUMBER 
                          AND DFS_RODETAIL.LINENUMBER = DFS_ROPART.LINENUMBER 
                          AND DFS_ROHEADER.RONUMBER LIKE '%$FF_RONumber%' 
                          AND DFS_ROHEADER.UNITNUMBER LIKE '%$FF_UnitNumber%' 
                          AND DFS_ROHEADER.PONUMBER LIKE '%$FF_PONumber%' 
                          AND ( DFS_CUSTOMER.BNAME LIKE '%$FF_Customer%' 
                                 OR DFS_CUSTOMER.BNAME IS NULL ) 
                          AND DFS_ROHEADER.TECHID LIKE '%$FF_TechID%' 
                          AND DFS_ROHEADER.CLOSEDDATE BETWEEN 
                              FF_ClosedBegin AND FF_ClosedEnd 
                          AND ( DFS_TECH.REGION LIKE '%$FilterRegion%' 
                                 OR DFS_TECH.REGION IS NULL ) 
                          AND ( DFS_TECH.RSM LIKE '%$FF_RSM%' 
                                 OR DFS_TECH.RSM IS NULL ) 
                          AND DFS_RODETAIL.STORY LIKE '%$FF_Story%' 
                          AND DFS_ROPART.PARTID LIKE '%$FF_PartID%' 
        WHERE  DFS_ROHEADER.DELETED_BY < 0 
               AND DFS_RODETAIL.DELETED_BY < 0 
               AND DFS_ROPART.DELETED_BY < 0) T 
ORDER  BY T.RONUMBER
```

This query works; however, it can take forever to run, and can timeout.  I have other queries that also run in the environment and I will take whatever you can give me in terms of suggestions and apply it to those. I am using SQLServer 2000, Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

Execution Plan:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99733863/ExecutionPlan.sqlplan

UPDATE:

I have come to the conclusion the environment I'm working in is the cause of the problem.  My query works as intended and is not slow at all (1 sec. for 18,000 rows).  As stated in the comments I have to fill grids with limited flexibility and I believe that these grids fill by first filling a temporary grid with the SQL statement and then copying row by row into the desired grid. There is a good chance that this is the cause of my issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you need `LIKE` in so many places, rather than `=`? `=` is far, far faster, even with indexes.

Comment: `LIKE` is partially required.  The user will put in a partial for the field to filter on.  I would like to keep it and I don't think my boss will be too fond of getting rid of it.

Comment: It sounds like this is based on a search form. In that case, only use the `LIKE` conditions that you need (i.e., where the variable is not `''`) -- otherwise, you're just creating extra work for the server.

Comment: I agree with Ed, additionally, using a leading '%' on every string is looking ANYWHERE in the column.  Is it possible to do partial searches but where the string STARTS with what is provided?  If so, removing the leading '%' WOULD be able to help based on available indexed columns.

Comment: I would have gladly done this, and thought of it as a solution first, but my environment doesn't allow me to easily accomplish this.  I would essentially have a different query for EACH scenario and I can only figure that out by having MANY if statements. (i.e. I can't use CASES or anything like it). I would have 36 separate queries 3 times over the grids I'm filling in the environment.

Comment: @DRapp We have a story field which needs to be searched anywhere and all the users are used to searching in the string anywhere for all fields. To have one app be different would throw them into a frenzy.

Comment: Please post the execution plan. Do you really need the distinct? This usually indicates a logic bug, or data model flaw.

Comment: @usr I have the execution plan pulled up in SSMS, but how should I post it? I don't really need the distinct and should have removed it after finding the real problem of duplicate data, I will edit shortly.

Comment: Upload the .sqlplan file (right click, save) to some file hoster or paste its contents into pastebin. What performance target do you have? How fast does this have to be?

Comment: It ran rather quickly in SMSS, so I wonder if it isn't my environment that's holding it up. Essentially in my environment I'm filling a grid with this data and the grid is a typical 2-dimensional array.  I'm not really looking for a specific target performance just to not have the user sit at the desk for 30+ seconds waiting on the query.

Comment: @usr The execution plan is available on the question under EDIT.

Comment: I don't see why the query would take especially long to execute. If the data is in-memory I'd expect this to run in seconds.; Can you add indexes? This query isn't especially hard to optimize if you can do that. If not I'm not sure what to do.; If you can add an indexed view you can remove the major joins entirely. That results in blazingly fast performance.

Comment: Please be aware of the pitfalls of using `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types, [especially on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Are all of those columns using `LIKE` already strings?  If not, they need to be converted first - and I'm not sure how helpful that kind of searching is for some of the likely values.  It would be better for you to put join criteria next to the actual reference (ie, move `AND DFS_ROHEADER.TECHID LIKE '%$FF_TechID%'`).  This query could be made dynamic, which may help.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse All of these are great suggestions, but first I have to convert to strings in SQL as they are already strings, but SQL throws a fit without converting in SQL. Second I was moving around my criteria in different locations so it was just a quick throw up there (which I should have moved around for readability), but will putting relevant table criteria next to the join help the query or just readability?  Last as stated in the question I am limited to what I can do in the environment query (i.e. just a select with criteria and joins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion the environment I'm working in is the cause of the problem.  My query works as intended and is not slow at all (1 sec. for 18,000 rows).  As stated in the comments I have to fill grids with limited flexibility and I believe that these grids fill by first filling a temporary grid with the SQL statement and then copying row by row into the desired grid. There is a good chance that this is the cause of my issues. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents here.. In general LIKE is not very well optimized. In your case you also seem to be using LIKE with '%value%'. In that case the query optimizer has to scan the entire index. At a minimum I would see if there is a way to avoid using this.

Comment: I would have loved to get away from all the `LIKE %value%`, but it is a requirement of the program.  Thanks for the input though.